# On Cassandra how to enable LDAP authentication

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cassandra-3.0, wide-column-store

I have a Cassandra cluster running on Ubuntu. I would like to enable authentication so that not everyone will have access to the Cassandra database and run queries.

Enabling simple authentication is available at https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/secureConfigNativeAuth.html

But, I am looking for integrating Cassandra with LDAP, Active Directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to change the default authenticator from AllowAllAuthenticator to PasswordAuthenticator or some custom authenticator.

You can also enable roles for a finer grained access.

Check the following:

- http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/security.html?highlight=authenticator#authentication
- https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/secureConfigNativeAuth.html

Later edit: since you need LDAP autentication you can use the one created by Instaclustr. Details - [Apache Cassandra LDAP Authentication](https://www.instaclustr.com/apache-cassandra-ldap-authentication/) and the [source code](https://github.com/instaclustr/cassandra-ldap).

Comment: I've found this information on datastax website. I am more looking for authentication against LDAP

Answer (score -1):

Just replace PasswordAuthenticator from AllowAllAuthenticator and CassandraAuthorizer from AllowAllAuthorizer on cassandra.yaml. Restart the Cassandra services. it will allow without password.